# Why doesn't google analytics code use AJAX

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I was wondering how ga collected data and send it to their servers, then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534524/how-does-the-embedded-google-analytics-javascript-work) on SO. Now I'm wondering why does GA uses this method rather than doing an AJAX request, is it cheaper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not cheaper, per se, it is reliable. Unlike AJAX, you can include an image from any domain without running into cross-domain browser restrictions, this is why tracking pixels are used instead of ajax requests.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob said, it's primarily to get around cross-domain issues not supported in older browsers. However, as of recently GA has added support for the [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.sendBeacon) method, which **actually is cheaper**, allows for retries on error, and doesn't have the problem of failing when the page is being unloaded (like when trying to send an event when a user clicks on an outbound link). As browser support increases, this will likely become the default method for sending hits to GA.

Here's the documentation on how to use `sendBeacon` with analytics.js:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#useBeacon

Comment: Looks like `useBeacon` is now deprecated in favor of [`transport`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport)